# OpenCart render front-end

Tags: templates, rendering, opencart, output

Hy all,

I'm trying to give users an confirmation message when they unsubscribe to an newsletter. But i'm only getting the confirmation message without the rest of the website.

[Here's the url so you can see what's going on...](http://www.gospel7.com/index.php?route=newsletter/unsubscribe&id=80003)

In the unsubscribe controller class i have this code to render the page:

```
$this->language->load('newsletter/unsubscribe');

$this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

$this->data['breadcrumbs'] = array();
$this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
    'text'      => $this->language->get('text_home'),
    'href'      => $this->url->link('common/home'),         
    'separator' => false
);

$this->template = 'default/template/newsletter/newsletter.tpl';
$this->children = array(
    'common/column_left',
    'common/column_right',
    'common/content_top',
    'common/content_bottom',
    'common/footer',
    'common/header' 
);

$this->response->setOutput($this->render());
```

My template file looks like this:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-heading">Uitschrijven</div>
    <div class="box-content">
        <div id="notification">
            <div class="success" style="">
                U bent succesvol uitgeschreven.
                <img src="catalog/view/theme/metroshop/image/close.png" alt="" class="close">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When i look at the other's ( the product controller or the account, and google ) it says that this is the right way to render the page ( with the childs like that ). But as you can see, the children ( the rest of the site ) isn't renderd.

What did i miss? Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, i've figured it out. I could delete my question, but mayby does this help others in the future so i'm answering it...

My template file looked like this:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-heading">Uitschrijven</div>
    <div class="box-content">
        <div id="notification">
            <div class="success" style="">
                U bent succesvol uitgeschreven.
                <img src="catalog/view/theme/metroshop/image/close.png" alt="" class="close">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That's only the content. But you also need to echo the header, footer and all that kind of stuff. So you've got to do something like thisedi:

```
<?php echo $header; ?>
<?php echo $column_left; ?>
<?php echo $column_right; ?>

<div id="content">
    <?php echo $content_top; ?>
    <h1 style="display: none;">
        <?php echo $heading_title; ?>
    </h1>
    <div class="box">
    <div class="box-heading">Uitschrijven</div>
    <div class="box-content">
        <div id="notification">
            <div class="success" style="">
                U bent succesvol uitgeschreven.
                <img src="catalog/view/theme/metroshop/image/close.png" alt="" class="close">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <?php echo $content_bottom; ?>
</div>

<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

And that's working fine now. Hope that this help's somebody in the future.